# Converting WebClient to HttpClient

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, httpclient, webclient

I have been surfing and working on this for hours now and I'm read to throw my PC.

I have a WebClient on WPF application that needs to be converted to HttpClient for UWP application.  I am getting a lot of header errors and since I'm not a web guru I am beating myself.

Here's the original and if someone would be extremely kind and help me convert it to HttpClient I would be very thankful.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string request = "------WebKitFormBoundarygWsJMIUcbjwBPfeL"
                    + Environment.NewLine
                    + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"guid\""
                    + Environment.NewLine
                    + Environment.NewLine
                    + presetSmall.PresetId.ToString()
                    + Environment.NewLine
                    + "------WebKitFormBoundarygWsJMIUcbjwBPfeL"
                    + Environment.NewLine
                    + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"delay\""
                    + Environment.NewLine
                    + Environment.NewLine
                    + "0"
                    + Environment.NewLine
                    + "------WebKitFormBoundarygWsJMIUcbjwBPfeL--"
                    + Environment.NewLine;

    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarygWsJMIUcbjwBPfeL");

    client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(ServerName + UriForPresetExecution), "POST", request);

}
```

The problem is in the client.Headers.Add method... I cannot for the sake of time figure out how HttpClient wants me to add those headers.

Comment: I know.  Seen the issue a lot.  The WebClient is much smarter that HttpClient.  I usually use a sniffer like fiddler or wireshark and capture http headers with working application (like your WebClient).   Then add missing headers to my HttpClient.

Comment: I realise that the keyword for this is "MultipartFormDataContent", instead of "content-type". But I failed to find a UWP example for you.

Comment: @kennyzx  Man you helped a lot.  I think your second answer works... However; I had to 'Clear' the headers before it would take.  I don't know why but I read others having the same issue and so I tried it and it worked.  Repost and I'll edit for the answer.

Comment: @kennyzx  It came down to this...             using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var httpContent = new StringContent(request);
                httpContent.Headers.Clear();
                httpContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarygWsJMIUcbjwBPfeL");

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, httpContent);
            }

Comment: thanks. But you don't need to mark it as answer since we don't know why it works this way.  You can offer an upvote instead ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) 
{ 
    var httpContent = new StringContent(request); 
    httpContent.Headers.Clear(); 
    httpContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarygWsJMIUcbjwBPfeL"); 
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, httpContent); 
}
```

Comment: This didn't work.  I got this exception. A method was called at an unexpected time.

Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.

Comment: hi, please try the alternative. The previous answer was what is working in a Windows Store app, I did not test it with UWP.

Comment: Nope, now I get - The format of value 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarygWsJMIUcbjwBPfeL' is invalid.  I'm really starting to dislike HttpClient :/

Comment: I've been trying every possible format I can find and or think of and nothing has gotten me anywhere.

Comment: but with the old WebClient, the same content-type header just works?

Comment: Yeah, it works just fine with the old.  I am running them together for testing as I do the work.

Comment: The call to httpContent.Headers.Clear() is what did the trick.  I'm not sure why :/  Thanks man, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Instead of clearing the headers and re-adding, you should use the StringContent (string, Encoding, string) constructor overload.